# UITextView crash when clicking on a URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I have the following lines in my code to add a clickable url to a UITextView. merchantwebsite is my UITextView.

```
self.merchantwebsite.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.crossfit.com" attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName: @"http://www.crossfit.com"}];
self.merchantwebsite.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

When I click on the UITextView, the app crashes with the log

```
2014-03-19 16:13:43.051 BTLE[27103:60b] -[__NSCFConstantString scheme]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a4404
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add linker flags -all_load and -ObjC in our project if you don't use them

Answer (score 6):

You evidently have code that expects the URL to be an NSURL. But, quite simply, an NSString is *not* an NSURL. Try it like this:

```
self.tv.attributedText = 
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
        initWithString:@"http://www.crossfit.com" 
        attributes:
            @{NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.crossfit.com"]}];
```

Comment: Agreed that's an `NSString` is not an `NSURL`. But the documentation says : `The value of this attribute is and NSURL object (preferred) or an NSString object.` So an `NSString` should work as expected. (If i test it, I can't reproduce the crash with an `NSString` with iOS 7.0 and iOS 7.1 simulator)

Comment: That is right @Emmanuel but the crash is being caused by other code that the OP did not show us. That is why I said "you evidently have code"... It's probably his text view's delegate that is causing the crash.

Comment: I know this is an old question now, but it seems that regardless of Apple saying that the attribute can be a string or an NSURL, the UITextViewDelegate method expects an NSURL, or you'll get the unrecognized selector crash

Answer (score 1):

Just type the link in when you are telling the UITextView what to display and then turn on link recognition in the settings on the right when your UITextView is selected from the .storyboard page.

You don't really need any of the code that you have all you need is:

```
merchantwebsite.text = @"http://www.crossfit.com";
```

Comment: The reason I use attributed text is to make the text look like a hyperlink.

Comment: then change the font sise and color (and maybe add an underline) to make it look like a link

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows:

```
 NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.crossfit.com" attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName: @"http://www.crossfit.com"}];
[self.merchantwebsite setAttributedText:string];
```